# Monitoring Azure Data Warehouse for uptime and scaling settings

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Is there a sys view or DMV that records the time my Data Warehouse was resumed and paused, the account doing the resuming and pausing?  I'm looking around and can't seem to find a view that has an on/off timestamp.  Or even a view that shows historical time stamps of scaling up and down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Activity Log which is available from the portal:

[image: Activity Log]

I am not aware of any DMVs that can answer this question but will update this post if I find one.

If you feel this is an important feature, please upvote this feature request:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/17014555-query-to-know-when-the-azure-sql-data-warehouse-wa